# kernel panic affected after install another arch linux

Tags: multi-boot, arch-linux, manjaro, kernel-panic

I had new ssd, I install blackArch on it. what I mean by affected is "not tainted" logged to screen, on very initial stage.

[image]
The old/ current linux is manjaro with :
Linux adi-80e1 5.10.109-1-MANJARO

it only runs with fallback init ram.

Post installation, the blackarch did even not recognize the old manjaro.

[config](https://gist.github.com/1c11a3be48825d96dff1372d668428eb)

Why is that and how to fix manjaro boot (either fix the boot load or creating the initram.rd)? I want both bootable smoothly, but now only the blackArch working.

Thank you :)

Comment: this title is very confusing, why would a kernel panic be "tainted"? did you mean "affected"? or something else? What were you expecting to happen, and what occurred instead?

Comment: that the error logged to the screen, IDK how to construct it in a better way.

Comment: maybe print the exact error? Or describe more? As it is now it isn't clear what you want, so this question is unanswerable.

Comment: oh, you mean "Kernel panic with 'not tainted' error after Arch Linux install"? You should put that in quotes if it's literally an error displayed to the screen, because otherwise it's rather strange. And "affected" doesn't work here at all, now that I understand what you meant (I think)

Comment: excellent, thanks for your cooperation. not yet can give the log.

Comment: which boot do you want fixed? The original one or blackarch? If the original, you need to reinstall the initramfs because the current one is likely corrupted

Comment: how? an answer would be nice, and a brief what is initramfs :)

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1718154/edit) your question to specifically fix booting your old Manjaro install then, and remove mention of the new BlackArch install, and I or someone else can try to answer that question. As of now, there is no clear question to answer.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612440/dual-booting-ubuntu-and-manjaro-manjaro-only-boots-in-initramfs-fallback-kernel does this help?

Comment: no, can you post an answer? basically I try that but can't find initramfs. I change the grub.cfg directly tho.